# How to do variable interpolation in hamlet?

Tags: haskell, interpolation, yesod, shakespeare-text

Say i want to display a random number everytime i refresh a page. Here's my code:

```
...
import System.Random
...

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
  randomX <- liftIO $ randomRIO (1,999::Int)
  defaultLayout $ do
    setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
    $(widgetFile "homepage")
    toWidgetBody [hamlet|<div>#{randomX}|]
```

That works fine.

I use the default scaffolded site. Now when I want to use  `#{randomX}` in `homepage.hamlet`

```
<div>#{randomX}
```

It gives me an error

```
Handler/Home.hs:37:11:
Not in scope: ‘randomX’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘randomR’ (imported from System.Random),
  ‘random’ (imported from System.Random),
  ‘randoms’ (imported from System.Random)
In the splice: $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

How do i apply variable interpolation in a hamlet file?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Are you including `$(widgetFile "homepage")` in some other handler? (what's in line number 37?)

Comment: Is this a Template Haskell staging restriction? (TH requires that any function you call is defined in a separate module - because otherwise it won't be compiled yet.)

Comment: I removed `$(widgetFile "homepage")` part in postHomeR to make it work. I don't know why it works though. Thanks for pointing that out @josejuan.

Comment: @ΗλεκτρολόγοςΜηχανικός "I don't know why it works though" think with `widgetFile` as a kind of macro expansion then, is clear why `randomX` is not defined (into `postHomeR`) :)

Comment: if homepage.hamlet contains #{randomX}, then you have to have a randomX value in scope everywhere $(widgetFile "homepage") is used.  If $(widgetFile "homepage") appears in both postHomeR and getHomeR, then you need to have a randomX defined in both postHomeR and getHomeR also.

Comment: For anyone else running into a similar error, you can use the line number in the error message to see which call to `widgetFile` is failing (line 37, in this case)